# Can ctags be made to follow #include directives?

Tags: vim, ctags

I am trying to create a target in my Makefile to automatically create a `tags` file using ctags.

I have a list of source files (.cpp files) but I don't have a list of all the header files (I use `g++ -MM` to create the list of header dependencies).

I would have assumed that ctags would follow any `#include` directives in the .cpp files when generating the tags, but it seems my assumption is wrong.

If I create a simple tags file like this:

```
ctags  --fields=+iaS --extra=+q myClass.cpp
```

and then go into vim and type in the name of an object followed by a  '.' I get the error "Pattern not found".

However, if I compile the tags file like this:

```
ctags  --fields=+iaS --extra=+q myClass.cpp myClass.h
```

and do the same thing in vim I get a lovely auto-completed list of member variables/functions.

The first line in my 'myClass.cpp' file is

```
#include "myClass.h"
```

So why doesn't ctags use that to parse the header file too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nope. unfortunately/fortunately.

There wouldn't be too many problems following your own includes. The problem starts with

- conditional compilation
- external (system) libraries.

Fortunately, the problem for your own libraries is easily solved by doing something like

```
ctags *.h *.cpp
ctags -R src/
```

You could hack something together with `cpp` and then `ctags`. It would not work conveniently. A half-interesting approach would be to patch ctags to follow the `#line` pragma's in `cpp`'s output and hence relate all tags to their respective sources.

However, that approach would *not* work as you'd expect for any preprocessor symbols/defines (macros have been expanded, so you wouldn't be able to find a macro by ctags).

**The usual way** to resolve this, is to generate a 'standard' tags file for your external libraries, and

```
:se tags+=/home/me/libs/tags.stdc++
:se tags+=/home/me/libs/tags.libsox
```

etc. Several libraries have tutorials on how to make a useful tags file for use with their libraries (or prebuilt tags files assuming a certain folder layout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After playing around with it for a little while longer I settled on the `ctags -R .` option. It's a shame, I was hoping for a `--follow-includes` option (maybe coupled with a `--include-depth=X` option). But like you say, the ability to have conditional `#include`s makes this tricky.