# vim set tags with absolute path

Tags: windows, vim, ctags

I work on multiple projects, each ~3-5 million lines of code. I have a single tags file at the root of each project. I also have a tools directory shared between all of them.

```
disk1
 |
 +--Proj A
 |
 +--Proj B
 |
 +--Shared

disk2
 |
 +--Proj C
 |
 +--Proj D
```

When using tags, I would like Vim to first search the tags file at the root of my project, and then search the tags file for `Proj X`, and then search the tags file in `Shared`

I can't get Vim to find the tags file in `Shared`

in my .vimrc file I have:

<strike>set tags=tags;D:/Shared</strike> 
`set tags=tags;,D:/Shared` (thanks to romainl for catching a missing comma!)

but Vim only searches the local project tags file, not the shared one.

`tags;` should start at the CWD and traverse back up the tree until a tags file is found (finds the correct one at the project level).

`D:/Shared` is an explicit path and should find the tags file in that directory but fails to do so (I've checked, it does in fact exist).

I'm using Exuberand Ctags v5.8

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336143/using-multiple-tag-files-at-once-in-vim-tag-organisation-in-general

Comment: So, I ended up creating a tags file for the shared components at the root-most level of the disk. This way the `tags=tags;` behavior can find it since it keeps traversing up until it finds something. The bummer though is that I now have to have two redundant copies of the shared tags file, one for each disk (Proj A and B on disk 1, Proj C and D on disk 2) -- the shared tags file is almost 1GB. It's not the space that Im complaining about (1GB is peanuts), it's the redundancy... I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set tags=tags;D:/Shared
```

means "look *upward* for a `tags` file from the current directory until you reach `D:/Shared`".

If you work in project C on disk 2 (let's call that disk `E:`), Vim will *never* visit `D:/Shared` because of two things:

1. Upward search is not recursive.

   If no `tags` file is found at the root of the "current directory", Vim tries to find one at the root of its parent and so on until it reaches the topmost parent or the directory you specified after the semicolon. So, supposing you are editing `E:\ProjectC\path\to\some\file`, you can't expect Vim to find a `tags` file outside of that path. Vim will search for the following `tags` files, sequentially and, by the way, *never* find that hypothetic `D:\Shared`:

   ```
   E:\ProjectC\path\to\some\tags <-- KO
   E:\ProjectC\path\to\tags      <-- KO
   E:\ProjectC\path\tags         <-- KO
   E:\ProjectC\tags              <-- OK!
   E:\tags                       <-- KO
   ```

   It won't find any `tags` file not listed above.
2. Windows doesn't have the equivalent of UNIX's "root" directory anyway.

   When you don't specify a stop directory, upward search climbs the inverted tree of your filesystem from the current directory (or an arbitrary start directory) to the root of the filesystem.

   Supposing you are still editing `E:\ProjectC\path\to\some\file`, upward search will ultimately look for the stop directory `D:\Shared` directly *under* every parent directory in the path to `E:\` and will rather obviously *never* find it.

If you want Vim to find `D:\Shared\tags` wherever you are, you only need to add it explicitely to the `tags` option. Not as a stop directory but as a specific location:

```
set tags=tags;,D:/Shared/tags
```

Now, it says "look upward for a `tags` file from the current directory *and* use `D:/Shared/tags`".

---

<sup>Hmm… that was a lot of words just to explain the need for a single `,`.</sup>

Comment: nice catch! I didn't mean to set D:/Shared as my stop directory, I wanted it to traverse to the root of the drive. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I get a "tag not found". I've verified that the tag in question in fact exists in my shared tags file.

Comment: I meant `set tags=tags;,D:/Shared/tags`, sorry.

Comment: I feel that the syntax for this is a bit clunky. I've been trained to see a semicolon as a full stop, the end of a command. So it feels awkward that the stop directory comes _after_ the semicolon... I would prefer the stop dir to come after a comma or something.